# Usage of 'attributable to' to describe a casual scenario

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to express a state of accustoming of a person to a certain circumstance, due to the consumption of alcohol.

> By this time, he was somewhat accustomed to the situation, attributable to the booze

I don't know if the usage of 'attributable' makes sense here, though.
Should I shoot for 'due to', instead? Is there any connotation in 'attributable' that won't fit in here?

Comment: ... *because of the booze* .

Comment: @Josh61 yeah sure, would be a possibility. I'm looking for an elevated variant though, that is less frequently to be seen

Comment: The fact that he got somewhat accustomed to the situation was attributable to the booze.

Comment: The title of the question mentions a "casual scenario", yet you want a more formal phrasing?  Fix the title!

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I don't think a casual scenario can't be depicted in a formal way. What title would you propose and why don't you fix it yourself if you're unhappy with it?

Comment: "booze" is a quite casual term. I can imagine the narrator saying "on account of the booze", which is even more folksy. But for the "elevated variant", try Josh61's suggestion.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock this was not intended as an offense. I am a non-native speaker and perhaps I don't get what I'm actually saying or I get it wrong. I try to describe the situation from outside. This narrator is not meant to be folksy, yet the consumer of the booze is. I think I'll shoot for your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I was rude. Your title is OK.

Comment: Actually, the title of the question is a little misleading.  The scenario (repeated drunkenness) isn't a "casual scenario" ; rather the *description* of the situation as the result of "booze" is the casual thing. We have the professional and serious "attributable to"  and the flippant and casual "booze".

Answer (score 2):

By this time, he was somewhat accustomed to the situation, the result of his boozing.

or
... the situation, brought on by his boozing.

or

... the situation brought on by his boozing.

"attributable to" and  "booze" are odd bedfellows.

"attributable to the excessive consumption of alcohol" is consistent register.

Comment: The tonal imbalance amd ruahing meter of ''attributable to the booze' is, imho, a great voice element. The surrounding text would be needed to tell whether that voice is appropriate,  though.

Comment: Just pointing the stark tonal contrast out to the OP without making any judgment with regard to the potential value of such contrast in a literary context, though I remain to be convinced of such value when the contrast arises within a single phrase :)  BTW,  I wasn't recommending "attributable to the excessive consumption of alcohol" -- just giving an example of a phrase in the same register.